# How do I format C# code in VisualStudio to capitalize the first letter

Tags: c#, visual-studio, coding-style

[image: 1]

When C# code style does not conform to the specification, using `.editconfig` only prompts. It cannot be automatically formatted. Use Ctr+K Ctr+D is not modified. Is there any shortcut to do this?

Comment: No, the reason and temporary solutions can be found here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/14983#:~:text=Here%20is%20a%20simple%20PowerShell%20Core%20script%20to,across%20classes%29%20foreach%20%28%24txt%20in%20Get-ChildItem%20-%20Path.

Comment: Are you saying that you want Visual Studio altering your code? My first reaction is the question how to avoid that :-)

Comment: There seems to be no good way to kill two birds with one stone for the time being, but for warnings you can set them through the editorconfig analyzer. For code that you do not want to be automatically formatted, you can add "#pragma warning disable format" and "#pragma warning disable format" before and after